# Regular expression for reference number

Tags: c#, regex

I need to write the regular expression to fit a specific code pattern: the string to match has 18 integer characters and I need to check if in the first position there is 0 and in the second one 8 or 9. I wrote this expression, but it doesn't work:

```
 Regex regex = new Regex(@"^(.{0}[0]{1}[8,9])(^\d{18}$)");
        string compare = "082008014385161873";
        if (regex.IsMatch(compare))
        {
            //true
        }
```

Anyone can help me?

Comment: Maybe you're already doing this, but there are several really helpful online regex testers around these days where you could iteratively refine your work and identify problems.  http://regex101.com/ is a good one.  And they enable permalinks to share work.  Here's your expression: http://regex101.com/r/pR7cA0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regular expression. It does the following:

- Verifies first digit as 0
- Verifies second digit as a 8 or 9
- Verifies that 16 more digits follow the first 2 digits

.

```
^0[89]\d{16}$
```

Answer (score 1):

Use following regular expression:

```
^0[89]\d{16}$
```

Alternative using positive lookahead assertion:

```
^(?=0[89])\d{18}$
```

Comment: Why I need to put 16 if the lenght of the string is expected to be 18?

Comment: Because the 0 and (8 or 9) are the other two digits.  1 + 1 + 16 = 18.

Comment: @Sara, `0[89]` consumes two strings, while positive lookaround assertion `(?=0[89])` does not consume.